# Location-aware geocoding on Android (just like Google Maps)

Tags: android, google-maps, location, geocoding

It seems that the search in the **Google Maps** app is **location aware**. For example, if I search for "Pitt St" while in Sydney, it finds the right street straight away. Clicking "Did you mean..." brings a list of other "Pitt St" close in **nearby suburbs**.

Is there a way to ge a similar experience in our apps? I tried the standard [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html), but a similar search returns "Pitt St, New York" as the first match.

- Is there a set of options I'm missing?
- Is there a different API we can use for this?
- As a last resort, do you think it's reasonable to implement this manually, for example by querying the Geocoder with a max radius of 1km, 10km, 100km, and then sorting the results by distance?

Cheers

Romain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which function did you use? `Geocoder.getFromLocationName()` takes a bounding box that allows you to limit the results to a certain region, so you could get the current GPS position first and pass that in.

Alternatively, you could go through the [Geocoder API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) which is more flexible, but also more restrictive in terms of the TOS, not to mention a lot more work to use. (I'm not sure if using it from an Android app is covered in the TOS, I haven't looked at it much).

Comment: I'm using getFromLocationName(String locationName, int maxResults). I thought about passing in a region, but it raises quite a few questions, for example: when to stop searching, when to increase the region, sort the results by distance or accuracy?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link about the other API, I will have a look at the kind of results it returns. I'm very curious how the Google Maps app does it and which API it uses.

Comment: Well, even if your GPS signal is off by 100 miles, Pitt St in Syndey will beat out Pitt St in New York. So get the signal, use an obscenely large bounding box, and get the results. (The signal will typically not be off by more than 1 - 1.5 miles, and you can get its accuracy). Once you get your results, sort them by distance. That should work in most cases.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I was hoping for something like getFromLocationName(String locationName, GeoPoint closeTo), but unless someone has heard of a library that does that I'll probably implement it your way. Cheers!

Comment: Well, using a bounding box around a point is essentially the same as "close to", you'll just need to manually sort the results by distance to the point once you get them.

Comment: The only significant difference for me is that the sorting is done on the client, so if the bounding box is quite large I have to request many results - while Google recommends around 1-5. In the other case I could ask for the top 2 and it would hopefully return the 2 closest / most accurate matches as computed by the server using a really smart algorithm :)

Comment: Around Sydney? Quite a few actually... But I can't make assumptions about what the user is searching for, and how close it is. I just need reasonable suggestions, and the best/closest match could be around the block or in New Zealand. Really like what the Google Maps app does. My current idea is to use your 5 miles approach, and if that returns nothing then extend to 10, and keep extending exponentially until we find something.

Comment: I think that is definitely your best approach. If you want to be funny, you could send out several requests (5mi/10mi/30mi) at the same time to make it faster (assuming that you're not bandwidth bound)... but just for a start, a simple approach (request, parse response, retry if no results) should do. Good luck! Btw, you guys in Syndey need more creativity. Multiple Pitt Streets? What's up with that?!

Comment: That's a good idea! I think I'll implement the ping/pong version first and see how it goes. And yep, there's a lot of small suburbs around the city and it's not rare to see the same street names recycled =) Thanks a lot for your help!