# how do i figure out how to debug this? HttpResponse

Tags: java, android, json, debugging, google-places-api

I'm trying to make a json object from the result of the googleplaces api.  But one line of code is causing me alot of problems.  My question is how the heck do i find what the issue is. I can't seem to catch the right exception (im a noob at debugging though).  The url that i am passing in has the value:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=34.7,-86.5&radius=16000&types=food&name=mcdonalds&sensor=true&key=(myApiCodeWhichImNOTPostingHere)

^i  do have the correct apicode and the link works ourside of android.

here is the method in question (highlighted is the line that is causing problems).

```
        public static JSONObject getTheJSON(String url){
                        JSONObject json=null;
                        try{
                            DefaultHttpClient myHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost myHttpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            //this line below is giving me problems (jumps streight to the catch Exception)
                            HttpResponse response = myHttpClient.execute(myHttpPost); 
            //this line above is giving me problems(jumps streight to the catch Exception)

                            String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                            json= new JSONObject(data);
                        //parse the JSONObject
                           } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                             catch (ClientProtocolException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                             catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                             catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                             catch (NullPointerException e){ Log.e("My APP", "exception: " + e.getMessage());}

    /* jumps to line below (skips the other catch exceptions)
 the log reads "null" since i use the "getMessage()" so thats not useful*/  

                     catch (Exception e ) { Log.e("My APP", "exception: " + e.getMessage());}
                            return json;  // returning the JSON object

                }
```

(Edit):
Here is the logcat. i think im getting a connection to factory client error

```
10-16 21:11:30.105: E/My APP(980): exception
10-16 21:11:30.345: E/MapActivity(980): Couldn't get connection factory client
```

Comment: you've not mentioned if you're getting any errors/exceptions and if so, the specific details of the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `e.getMessage()`, use `e.printStackTrace()` (outside of the `Log.e()` method, but within the `catch` clause) so you can trace what the real problem is. If you do not get any wiser from that, please post the stacktrace here.

Edit (see commments):

My LogCat (without filters) always displays the stacktraces in a correct way, but after a bit of searching it seems that that is not always the case:
[See this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217500/how-to-print-stacktrace-for-an-exception-android)

You should use three(!) arguments with the `Log.e` method.
Example:

```
Log.e("My APP", "exception", e);
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: The question is how to debug his code. Not what the problem in the code itself is.
I think it is an answer to his question.

Comment: catch (Exception e ) { Log.e("My APP", "exception: " + e.getMessage());  e.printStackTrace();}

so you are saying like that? now my question is how do i find the error message? i am 100% sure that this line is being executed but i  have never understood how to find the message in logcat

Comment: Ah. My LogCat (without filters) always displays the stacktraces in a correct way, but after a bit of searching it seems that that is not always the case:
[See this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217500/how-to-print-stacktrace-for-an-exception-android).
You should use three(!) arguments with the `Log.e` method. Example:
`Log.e("My APP", "exception", e);`
Sorry to have misinformed you before.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check your SSL setup. You are calling a https:// url

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code in eclipse and it ran fine giving me a valid response. I think this is probably SSL related. You could enable SSL debugging by doing `-Djavax.net.debug=all`

Can you paste the output log after enabling SSL debugging?

Comment: sorry but im really new to this. can you explain how to do -Djavax.net.debug=all ? im just not sure where to put that...

Comment: -Djavax.net.debug=all is a java virtual machine argument. If you're using Eclipse as your ide, Run-->Run Configurations-->Arguments. Hope this helps.

Comment: can you look at the screenshot i posted? i go to Run-->RunConfigurations but i dont see "Arguments" anywhere. If this was just a normal java class i would know where to find it but i cant find it in android. thanks alot, Adam

Comment: sorry, i'm not familiar with android development so I'm not sure either.